# GRPC - Python Not able to send message greater than 4 MB

Tags: grpc

I am currently using grpc version 1.9.0. The GRPC python client seems like throwing error when msg size is greater than 4MB

```
Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, Received message larger than max
```

Does any one know how to handle this ? 
Specifying below does not work

```
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel(conn_str, options=[('grpc.max_send_message_length', 1000000 * 1000),
                               ('grpc.max_receive_message_length', 1000000 * 1000)])
```

Have tried to google a lot but in vain

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using GRPC Python Cython layer: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython

For example if you want 100MB max message_lenght options will be:

```
options = [(cygrpc.ChannelArgKey.max_send_message_length, 100 * 1024 * 1024),
           (cygrpc.ChannelArgKey.max_receive_message_length, 100 * 1024 * 1024)]
```